# How to create an array of IDirect3DSurface9 (D3D surfaces) surfaces in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, directx, direct3d

If I want to create a D3D surface I do it like below. Similiarly if I want to create an array of D3D surfaces of type IDirect3DSurface9* how do I do in C++ ?

```
IDirect3DSurface9** ppdxsurface = NULL;
IDirect3DDevice9 * pdxDevice = getdevice(); // getdevice is a custom function which gives me //the d3d device. 

pdxDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(720,480,
                                                D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
                                                D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
                                                pdxsurface,
                                                NULL);
```

**QUERY :: How do I create an array of D3D device in C++ ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ppdxsurface` is not declared correctly, you need to provide pointer to **pointer object**, not just pointer to pointer. It shall be `IDirect3DSurface9*`, not `IDirect3DSurface9**`:

```
IDirect3DSurface9* pdxsurface = NULL;
IDirect3DDevice9* pdxDevice = getdevice();

pdxDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(720, 480,
   D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
   &pdxsurface, // Pass pointer to pointer
   NULL);

// Usage:
HDC hDC = NULL;
pdxsurface->GetDC(hDC);
```

To create array of surfaces just call it in loop:

```
// Define array of 10 surfaces
const int maxSurfaces = 10;
IDirect3DSurface9* pdxsurface[maxSurfaces] = { 0 };

for(int i = 0; i < maxSurfaces; ++i)
{
   pdxDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(720, 480,
      D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
      &pdxsurface[i],
      NULL);
}
```

Or using `std::vector` if you prefer dynamic arrays:

```
std::vector<IDirect3DSurface9*> surfVec;

for(int i = 0; i < maxSurfaces; ++i)
{
   IDirect3DSurface9* pdxsurface = NULL;
   pdxDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(720, 480,
      D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
      &pdxsurface,
      NULL);
   surfVec.push_back(pdxsurface);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will "IDirect3DSurface9* pdxsurface[maxSurfaces] = { 0 };"   create the memory for the array of 10  elements, because we have just instantiated 1 element {0}. Shouldn't we do {0,0,......maxSurfaces(10) no: of times} ?

Comment: @codeLover No, array memory is created by declarartion. `{}` is just initialization list. We initialized first element with `0` to show that array is initialized. The rest of elements will be default-initialized (zeroed) automatically. Actually it is equivalent to your proposition: `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, but much shorter.

Comment: :: When I do this way {0} or even {0,0,......0} , I am getting the build error, expected constant expression & cannot allocate an array of size 0.

Comment: @codeLover Looks like you missed something with syntax. Double check it. It's proven to compile with VS2003+